# Facing ACPI Error: AE_NOT_Found and ucsi_acpi errors while booting into kali linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, nvidia, acpi, parrotsec

I made a fresh install of Kali-Linux 2020.2 on my new laptop. But when I try to boot up  Kali,  am facing these 2 errors,

> 1. ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND  (without any cmd line arguments, booting stops at [ 1.035097])
> 2. usci_acpi error.          (with *nomodeset* argument in cmd, booting stops at [ 9.803092])

By pressing **Ctrl+Alt+F4** I managed to get a console login and updated the whole system and installed Nvidia drivers. But the error still exists. Detailed *dmesg* errors and warnings are listed below.

---

System Specifications:

- Asus TUF Gaming A15
- AMD Ryzen 5 4600H
- Nvidia GTX 1650 4GB

---

> Output of **dmesg --level=err,warn**

```
[ 0.000000] secureboot: Secure boot could not be determined (mode 0) 
[ 0.017568] You have booted with nomodeset. This means your GPU drivers are DISABLED 
[ 0.017568] Any video related functionality will be severely degraded, and you may not even be able to suspend the system properly 
[ 0.017569] Unless you actually understand what nomodeset does, you should reboot without enabling it 
[ 0.322945] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP4.WLAN], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200110/dswload2-162) 
[ 0.322951] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200110/psobject-220) 
[ 0.340334] Expanded resource Reserved due to conflict with PCI Bus 0000:00 
[ 1.034969] ACPI: Invalid passive threshold 
[ 1.034994] ACPI: Invalid active0 threshold 
[ 1.035071] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.THRM._SCP.CTYP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200110/psargs-330) 
[ 1.035097] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.THRM._SCP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200110/psparse-529) 
[ 1.036639] i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp 
[ 1.586828] clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU2: Marking clocksource 'tsc-early' as unstable because the skew is too large: 
[ 1.587972] clocksource: 'hpet' wd_now: 10917ec wd_last: e14c30 mask: ffffffff 
[ 1.589554] clocksource: 'tsc-early' cs_now: 1ff0202172 cs_last: 1f95775cc2 mask: ffffffffffffffff 
[ 1.591177] TSC found unstable after boot, most likely due to broken BIOS. Use 'tsc=unstable'. 
[ 1.609342] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN1203:00: i2c-ELAN1203:00 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator 
[ 1.610351] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN1203:00: i2c-ELAN1203:00 supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator 
[ 1.699140] [drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting. 
[ 3.964308] process '/usr/bin/fstype' started with executable stack 
[ 4.370579] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[ 4.371394] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel. 
[ 4.372181] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint 
[ 4.440198] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module 440.82 Wed Apr 1 20:04:33 UTC 2020 
[ 4.522513] sp5100-tco sp5100-tco: Watchdog hardware is disabled 
[ 4.577906] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [IIA3] at bit offset/length 96/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (96 bits) (20200110/dsopcode-198) 
[ 4.577916] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.ATKD.WMNB due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20200110/psparse-529) 
[ 4.587343] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [IIA3] at bit offset/length 96/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (96 bits) (20200110/dsopcode-198) 
[ 4.589831] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.ATKD.WMNB due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20200110/psparse-529) 
[ 4.592536] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [IIA3] at bit offset/length 96/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (96 bits) (20200110/dsopcode-198) 
[ 4.592539] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.ATKD.WMNB due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20200110/psparse-529) 
[ 4.592668] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [IIA3] at bit offset/length 96/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (96 bits) (20200110/dsopcode-198) 
[ 4.592671] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.ATKD.WMNB due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20200110/psparse-529) 
[ 4.592686] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [IIA3] at bit offset/length 96/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (96 bits) (20200110/dsopcode-198) 
[ 4.592687] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.ATKD.WMNB due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20200110/psparse-529) 
[ 4.592698] asus-nb-wmi: probe of asus-nb-wmi failed with error -5 
[ 4.615355] [drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting. 
[ 4.726989] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load rtw88/rtw8822c_fw.bin (-2) 
[ 4.729655] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware 
[ 4.729658] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtw88/rtw8822c_fw.bin failed with error -2 
[ 4.729661] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to request firmware
[ 4.735775] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load rtw88/rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin (-2) 
[ 4.735777] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtw88/rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin failed with error -2 
[ 4.735781] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to request firmware 
[ 4.735965] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to load firmware
[ 4.735967] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to setup chip efuse info 
[ 4.735969] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to setup chip information 
[ 4.738004] kvm: disabled by bios 
[ 4.739410] rtw_pci: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -22 
[ 4.866478] kvm: disabled by bios 
[ 4.882458] uvcvideo 1-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Realtek Extended Controls Unit was not initialized! 
[ 4.882460] uvcvideo 1-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized! 
[ 4.882460] uvcvideo 1-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized! 
[ 4.882461] uvcvideo 1-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized! 
[ 4.960948] kvm: disabled by bios 
[ 5.074442] kvm: disabled by bios 
[ 5.197985] kvm: disabled by bios 
[ 5.315750] kvm: disabled by bios 
[ 5.415478] kvm: disabled by bios 
[ 5.506279] kvm: disabled by bios 
[ 5.651492] kvm: disabled by bios 
[ 5.774604] kvm: disabled by bios 
[ 9.803092] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109608/discussion-on-question-by-akshay-facing-acpi-ae-not-found-problem-while-booting).

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, amdgpu-drm and some missing network driver were causing the problem. In default, kali-Linux was using amdgpu-drm, so I hade to update the whole system and install Nvidia drivers through tty1. Pass `nvidia-drm.modeset=1`as boot argument for the first boot.

**Step 1:** Update the whole system.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

**Step 2:** Download the latest Linux-firmware from [Here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git).

```
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

**Step 3:** Copy the missing firmware to /lib/firmware/

```
sudo cp -r {clone's_PATH}/linux-firmware/{rtw88,rtl_nic,nvidia,amdgpu} /lib/firmware/
```

**Step 4:** Update the kernel with new changes (Don't worry it will list some amdgpu as missing firmware).

```
sudo update-initramfs -k all -u
```

**Step 5:** Installing Nvidia driver.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver nvidia-xconfig nvidia-kernel-common
```

**Step 6:** Configure Nvidia driver to create new configuration /etc/X11/xorg.conf (make sure you delete old xorg.conf.)

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

**Step 7:** Purge, reinstall nvidia drivers, and generate xconfig

```
sudo apt purge nivida* && sudo apt install nvidia-driver nvidia-xconfig && sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

**Step 8:** Update the grub configuration to pass `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` as default command.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
update the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nvidia-drm.modeset=1"
```

**Step 9:** update the grub, remove xorg.conf (let sys generate xorg.conf at reboot), and reboot the system.

```
sudo update-grub && sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf && sudo reboot
```